# Setting Custom Values on Extended class

Tags: c#, extending-classes

Im not sure if it is possible. I am running into a unique issue dealing with a clients api.
I am needing to extend a class and add a bool property that does not exist in the base class.

below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
public class baseClass
{
    //.. No Editable Access
}

public class Extended
{
    public bool flaggedAsDeleted(this baseClass bc)
    {
        //Idealy was looking for get; set; but I know that don't work
        return true;// Need to know if possible to set property on baseClass or Alternative
    }

    public void flagAsDeleted(this baseClass bc)
    {
        flaggedAsDeleted = true;
    }
}

public class program
{
    public void doit()
    {
        baseClass bc = new baseClass();
        bc.flagAsDeleted();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to actually *extend* a class, you do it like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    //.. No Editable Access
}

public class Extended : BaseClass
{
    public bool FlaggedAsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

If you're trying to add data to an existing class, you have two options:

1. Inheritance - as seen above.
2. Encapsulation - create a new object that holds an instance of the type you're adding to.

---

C# provides a feature called [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), which allows you to seemingly add methods to existing classes. However, these are really just syntactic sugar, as you're still constrained to the class's public API.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Increment(this BaseClass b)
    {
        b.Value += 1;
    }
}
```

Extension methods do not allow you to add data to an existing class though.

Comment: Thank you for your post and quick response.  The information you provided was insightful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not unique.  This is a common problem solved using a Design Pattern called [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).